# Text is jumbled in custom cell

Tags: swift, uitableview, core-data, cell

I'm trying to read data from CoreData into a custom cell. This is just a test app before I try moving to the real app that I've been working on. The data is there - I can print it to the console and see it. For some reason, even with constraints, all of the data is laid on top of each other in the cell. Can anyone see what's going on with this?

I've created constraints to keep the cells where they should be, but when the data is loaded from my 'show data' button, the data is laid on top of each other.

Here is my custom cell class:

```
import UIKit

class CustomCellClass: UITableViewCell {


    @IBOutlet weak var txtNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var txtAgeLabel: UILabel!



}
```

Here is the ShowData class: (partial)

```
class ShowData: UIViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var personTableView: UITableView!


    let appDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

    var personData = [Person]()

    // Read the data

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        personTableView.delegate = self
        personTableView.dataSource = self

        loadItems()
    }

  func loadItems() {
        let request : NSFetchRequest<Person> = Person.fetchRequest()
        do {
           personData = try appDelegate.fetch(request)
        } catch {
            print("couldn't load")
        }

    }

}

extension ShowData : UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return personData.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let person = personData[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "personNameAge", for: indexPath) as! CustomCellClass


        cell.txtNameLabel?.text = person.name
        cell.txtAgeLabel?.text = String(person.age)

        return cell

    }
```

Here is a screenshot of the tableview while running:
[image]

*Edit*:

I just deleted the app from the simulator and tried to rerun - now there isn't any data in the cells.

[image: Storyboard Constraints]
[image: Storyboard for ShowData Class]

Comment: Deleting the app and reinstalling left you with a new fresh copy of your data.

Comment: The “garbled” text is just overlapping labels due to incorrect constraints.

Comment: Now that you have edited your question and added the screenshot of your intra-cell constraints as I explained in my answer, I think the problem is obvious:  Your *Txt Name Label* and *Txt Age Label* both have a *.leading* constraint of *leading + 15*.  One of them should have a *.leading* constraint dependent on the other one, as in my answer.  For example, in my answer, *EditButton.leading = PerformButton.trailing*.  Or one of them should be pinned to the leading edge and the other to the trailing edge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to clarify for other readers, as can be seen in your screenshot, the *rows* in your table are separated as expected but the different fields in each cell, what one might call the *columns*, are on top of one another.

You say that you have *created constraints to keep the cells where they should be*, I'm not sure what you mean by that.  What you need is constraints for the fields within each cell – what I call *intra-cell constraints*.  Either you have not added these constraints, or there is a mistake in them which causes all fields to be drawn at the left.

To show you what I mean, let's use the example of a little workout app of mine which has, in each table cell, from left to right, a *Perform* button, an *Edit* button, a *Name* field and a *Duration* field.  The screenshot below shows, in the big yellow box, the intra-cell constraints.  If you are using a storyboard, the problem with your app must be in that area.  If you are not using a storyboard, the problem must be in the equivalent code (or lack of it).

[image]

Comment: Thanks Jerry! I've added my constraint screenshots. I have everything listed as you have up there. I'm not seeing any data in the table at the moment, and I can't figure out why it doesn't seem to be added it to the cell.

Comment: Okay, rmaddy was correct. I added new data and I'm getting the jumbled mess again.

Answer (score 0):

Just to let everyone know. The issue is resolved. I removed the table view cell from the project, readded, and readded the constraints. Everything is working now. I'm not sure where the problem was, but I noticed I had weird wrapping happening. I moved one of the labels to the other side of the cell and constrained it to the right side, and the other to the left side. When I ran the app, the text appeared to word wrap. I decided to delete the cell and readd and relink my outlets. It worked the first time...